# why doesn't libstdc++ on freebsd require a link to libc.so?

Tags: linux, freebsd, libstdc++

On freebsd libstdc++.so doesn't link to libc.so, but it must call functions like open, close and so on. Why isn't it listed in the output of ldd below like it is say on Linux?

```
freebsd$ ldd libstdc++.so
libstdc++.so:
 libm.so.2 => /usr/lib/libm.so.2 (0x21113000)

linux$ ldd libstdc++.so.6
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2d316000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fdd043e9000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdd04066000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdd04995000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fdd03e4f000)
```

Comment: What FreeBSD version are you trying this on?  From the libm.so version, it would appear to be pretty old.  At any rate, at least on FreeBSD 7.X, 8.X, and 9.X ldd libstdc++.so shows libc.so in the output.

Comment: It is old, FreeBSD 4.11. Does this imply that libc.so is somehow linked into libstdc++.so statically on this version?

Comment: I don't think so, but it looks that it was not a problem anyway, since any program is normally linked with libc and thus whatever symbols libstdc++ was using from libc it was able to resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

`open()`, `close()` functions are not from `libc`. they are native FreeBSD APIs

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by native here. But in both cases on Linux and on Freebsd I assume the open() user call must call the kernel somehow, in the case of linux is it though libc via a syscall, or interrupt dispatch, in the case of freebsd it is done how?